# Conditioning access to private key?

Tags: protocol-design, pki

I would like to provide a public/private keypair to a user, but require that the user obtain an authorizing key before being allowed to use the private key.  I don't want the authorizing party to have the private key -- instead, it should have something like a key-encrypting key that the user can use to decrypt the private key.  (Another way of looking at it: the user has a keypair with a password-encrypted key, but he does not know the password.  When he wants to use the key, the authorizer sends the password so the user can unlock the key.)

I think PKCS#12 offers a way to give the keypair to the user so that he can save it using normal OS facilities: PKCS#12 allows you to package certificates, keys and arbitrary secrets in a file that a security manager knows how to unpack and store.  But I'd like to accomplish all this with a minimum of "copy password *here* and paste over *there*," etc.  Ideally, sequence would be:

**Setup:**

Alice: generate keypair, encrypt private, send key-encryption-key to Bob, save `{public, KEK[private]}`

**Use:**

Alice: get `{public, KEK[private]}` from storage
Alice: authenticate to Bob
Bob: send KEK to Alice
Alice: decrypt `private`, use keypair

The authenticate/send KEK/decrypt private sequence should be as automatic as possible; ideally, it would look the same as Alice typing a password that would be processed locally to unlock her private key.

I'm aware that Alice could just save `KEK` or leave `private` unencrypted, but that's her problem.  The point of the method is to split the single point of failure between Alice and Bob, so that an attacker who wants to read Alice's email would have to compromise *both* Alice (to get `KEK[private]`) *and* Bob (to get `KEK`)

Does this sound like a canonical use pattern that I'm just not seeing?  Any ideas for a data structure for Alice's information that will work with traditional PKI tools?

Comment: Alice can of course just protect the private key on her own and keep using it with your scheme. If this is about using a private key for authentication, I'd just rather require additional signatures / timestamps / tokens etc. to be present.

Comment: I have a use case where 100% client-side encryption (with cloud-based data storage) would be almost enough, but I want to add a bit of protection from a purely client-side exploit.  If Alice has all her keys, then an attacker can see Alice's docs by compromising her machine (alone).  If Alice (alone) doesn't have all the necessary key material, then an attacker needs to hit both Alice and the cloud-storage / authenticator Bob.  My arrangement allows Alice to be sloppier with her keys (I don't _want_ her to be sloppy, but people inevitably are). [...]

Comment: Even if Alice discloses her keys (or, in a scenario I care about, she prints her plaintext keys [with the private key encrypted `KEK[private]`] on her will) her heirs can recover her data by convincing Bob that they are the next of kin and are entitled to get `KEK`.  If Alice died with just a password-protected private key, the heirs would be stuck trying to guess the password.

Comment: Hum, I'd just write an application on top of a key store. If you're going to write the private key to file it's too late anyway. Often good keystores are available on devices provided by the runtime. For backup, use backup, possibly within the same organisation.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing; I just want to do it in a way that's not totally wonky from standard key-store operations.  I have MacOS, Linux & Windows machines, which all have some sort of key/certificate management (it seems to be migrating from within the browser, although Firefox still seems to have an internal key store).  I figure if I can count on the key store to save a certificate and an encrypted private key (and return it on demand), I can deal with the rest in my application.  So I'm looking for a format that many/most key stores will save & return without a lot of hassle.

Comment: "without a lot of hassle" now that's a statement that I generally do not associate with security :) Anyway, getting too chatty, I'll delete this comment in a second.